# jQuery expression throws error after upgrading to 2.1

Tags: jquery

I recently switched from jQuery 1.7 to 2.1. Right now, the following expression - which worked before - throws a syntax error (unrecognized expression):

```
find("#[class*='item_id']:contains('_row_key')")
```

(shortened version of my original code)

Somebody knows why?
Thanks

EDIT:

This is the full code line

```
var rowKey = $("[id*='FormView']").find("#[class*='item_id']:contains('_row_key')").parent().children(".item_value").html();
```

Comment: @vinayakj What still do you require buddy?

Comment: Just added the full code in my question .. Now I don't understand what they changed in jQuery 2.1 regarding selectors

Comment: It is jQuery as the OP has tagged.

Comment: I am not sure, but clarity could have been better as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess for the support of the older selectors, you might be needing [jQuery Migrate 1.2.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/) and that will help you have both the older jQuery functionality with the power of newer ones too!

Just add the following line after your jQuery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

**Update**

Can you change your code to:

```
find("*[class*='item_id']:contains('_row_key')");
// ---^
// Or simply...
find("[class*='item_id']:contains('_row_key')");
```

I guess the `#` itself is wrong there! It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to support older selectors .. I'd like to update the expression to the "new" standard. Perhaps you know what should that be?

Comment: @reeax There's a mistake in your code. Can you check my updated answer now?

Comment: I wrote find("[class*='item_id']:contains('_row_key')"); (without the *) and it seems to work! I don't know why it firstly worked with jQuery 1.7 .. thanks a lot @Praveen Kumar

Comment: I tried, but need 15 reputation points so that my vote is visible !! New stackoverflow account, lost old email/password. It will work as soon as I get few more points.

Comment: clicked, it's green now :)